# Robot Framework - Can't set Object for Attribute using Execute JavaScript

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I want to set Object for value attribute using Execute Javascript but it doesn't work with robot framework (it work with C#) 
 Keyword:

```
InputTeasersForPageType
    [Arguments]    ${id}
    ${result}=    Set Json Value    {"PageId":"${id}"}    /PageId    "${id}"
    ${json_string}=    Stringify Json    [${result}]
    Unselect Frame
    Select Frame    id=ctl00_ctl00_FullRegion_EditPanelDiv
    Log    ${json_string}
    Execute Javascript    window.document.getElementById('ctl00_FullRegion_PC_109_1_EditForm_ctl18_hidValues').getAttribute('value');
    Execute Javascript    window.document.getElementById('ctl00_FullRegion_PC_109_1_EditForm_ctl18_hidValues').setAttribute('value',${json_string});
```

Comment: what is executed in server logs? does it escape `${json_string}` automatically?

Comment: It will be like that "[{\"PageId\": \"1372909\"}]"

Comment: in which way it doesn't work? it's just not setting value for it? there are no errors (in server console or in some debug mode) when that command is executed? (ps: I haven't worked with Robot Framework, but I have worked with webdriver on node)

Comment: Thanks for that ! It's worked , because i inspect so fast before testcase is done so it's not setAttribute ^^

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this I think it should work
Execute Javascript `window.document.getElementById('ctl00_FullRegion_PC_109_1_EditForm_ctl18_hidValues').value='${json_string}'`